# Show, by example, that we can find social welfare functions which satisfy any three of the four Arrow's axioms.

Tags: game-theory, economics, decision-theory, voting-theory, social-choice-theory

I want to show, by example, that we can find social welfare functions which satisfy any three of the four Arrow's axioms.

Given at least three rewards, and at least two individuals, there is no social welfare function meeting the *4 axioms* given by:

1. Unrestricted domain (full ordering requried)
2. No dictatorship (no individual whose preferences automatically become the group's)
3. Pareto's condition (if each individual has a particular preference, so does the group)
4. Independence of irrelevant alternatives (If a reward is removed, and everyone keeps the same preferences then so should the group)

Note that a *social welfare function* is a function which operates on preference profiles, obeying comparability and transitivity, and yields a group preference $\geq_g$ over the rewards which obeys comparability and transitivity.

Can you help me find an example where $3$ of the conditions hold?

Many thanks

Comment: What have you tried and can already do? An example which breaks 2 and keeps the others should not be terribly difficult, for example.

Comment: There’s only one social welfare function that violates (2), so for one example all that you have to do is check that it satisfies the other three axioms. For the others, have you learned about any of the standard functions (Borda count, plurality, plurality with elimination, pairwise comparison, etc.)?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott yes I have heard of a few of these. So the simple majority rule satisfies $D$, $P$, $I$, but not $U$. And I realised that we can see the social welfare function that violates $D$ is if we just choose $1$ person, whose individual preference is the group preference. Would any of these two do? I am not sure about the Borda Count example

Comment: @thinker: Yes, those two examples are fine. Borda count violates I; it's not too hard to cook up examples. Give it a try; if you can't come up with one, you can probably find one fairly easily online, and if all else fails, I can help. For P, try an *inverse dictator*: the function simply inverts the preferences of one fixed individual.